# Is the word a or an used if it is in front of 80%?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence I'd like to use: I reviewed the applications of those who passed the written test with an 80% or higher.

Answer (score 1):

*An* is correct, because the number **80**, when pronounced, starts with a vowel.

Comment: But isn't "80 percent" in plural form here? Shouldn't it be "an 80% or higher score" OR "80% or higher"?

Comment: @hauron no, numbers are singular. I don't know if it's because eighty (or whichever number) represents a collective of whatever's being counted, which makes intuitive sense to me personally, but whatever the reason the number itself is singular.

Comment: @568ml but the percent aren't - there's 80 of them ;)

Comment: @hauron Hmmm. I've re-read your question a fee times and I'm now of the opinion that it could work both with and without the indefinite article. I won't delete my comment, as I wish to leave behind a small, embarrassing monument to my own haste and stupidity, but please disregard it :) I have by now read the question too many times to be confident in proposing my own answer, as continually re-parsing it has caused my brain to auto-labotomise.

Comment: @568ml I know the pain, and thanks for the rare (and hopefully not last here) occasion for a witty comment right on time :)

Answer (score 0):

"I reviewed the applications of those who passed the written test with 80% or higher".

No indefinite article is necessary -- in fact, it *should not* be used here.

Comment: Although if implicitly "80%" is considered "80% score", then it could work (I know, I know, it's adding something to the sentence that wasn't there). Imagine a conversation: "what's your score?" "I've got an eighty percent (score)"

Comment: Agreed.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

For the sentence you've given, I'd use *an* just like you have. "an 80%" implies *score* or *grade* following it (imo):

> I reviewed the applications of those who passed the written test with an 80% [score] or higher.

You *wouldn't* use it in a sentence such as:

> I reviewed the applications of those who got 80% [of the questions] correct on the written test.

Of course, the entire phrase *could* be implied, leaving you with:

> I reviewed the applications of those who passed the written test with 80% or more [of the questions correct].

It really depends on usage, but I'd say there's nothing wrong with it as written.